# Python Post call throwing 400 Bad Request

Tags: python, rest, curl

I am writing a python script which will call a REST POST endpoint but in response I am getting  400 Bad Request where as if I do same request with curl, it returns me 200 OK. Code snippet for python script is below

```
import httplib,urllib
def printText(txt):
  lines = txt.split('\n')
  for line in lines:
      print line.strip()

httpServ = httplib.HTTPConnection("127.0.0.1", 9100)
httpServ.connect()

params = urllib.urlencode({"externalId": "801411","name": "RD Core","description": "Tenant create","subscriptionType": "MINIMAL","features":   {"capture":False,"correspondence": True,"vault": False}})

 headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
 httpServ.request("POST", "/tenants", params, headers)
 response = httpServ.getresponse()
 print response.status, response.reason
 httpServ.close()
```

and corresponding curl request is

```
curl -iX POST \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '
{
    "externalId": "801411",
    "name": "RD Core seed data test",
    "description": "Tenant for Core team  seed data testing",
    "subscriptionType": "MINIMAL",
    "features": {
        "capture": false,
        "correspondence": true,
        "vault": false
    }
}' http://localhost:9100/tenants/
```

Now I am not able figure out where is the issue in python script.

Comment: Please don't put an image in your question. Please copy and paste the **text**, not an image of the text, into your question.

Comment: I would suggest copy and pasting your code into the post and not using screenshots. This will allow people to more quickly help you out as they can test your code.

Comment: Screenshot removed and python code snippet added

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try using `requests` (install with `pip install requests`) instead of `urllib`.

Also, enclose your data as `JSON` in the request body, don't pass them as URL parameters. You are passing `JSON` data in your `curl` example as well.

```
import requests


data = {
    "externalId": "801411",
    "name": "RD Core",
    "description": "Tenant create",
    "subscriptionType": "MINIMAL",
    "features": {
        "capture": False,
        "correspondence": True,
        "vault": False
    }
}

response = requests.post(
    url="http://localhost:9100/tenants/",
    json=data
)

print response.status_code, response.reason
```

**EDIT**

From https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests:

> Note, the `json` parameter is ignored if either `data` or `files` is passed.
>
> Using the `json` parameter in the request will change the `Content-Type`
>   in the header to `application/json`.

Comment: Thanks, my error was because of using `data` instead of `json` in request :-)

Comment: Had same issue with requests.put - was incorrectly passing data = {} which was failing with http 400 - when I used json = {} it succeeded.  Thank you setevoy, Dusan Madar

Comment: thanks a lot , i tried lot
finally it worked for  response = requests.post(
    url="http://localhost:9100/tenants/",
    json=data
)

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is, you set `Content-Type` header as `application/json` and not sending data in json format

```
 import httplib, json

 httpServ = httplib.HTTPConnection("127.0.0.1", 9100)
 httpServ.connect()
 headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
 data = json.dumps({
    "externalId": "801411",
    "name": "RD Core",
    "description": "Tenant create",
    "subscriptionType": "MINIMAL",
    "features": {
        "capture": False,
        "correspondence": True,
        "vault": False
    }
 })
 # here raw data is in json format
 httpServ.request("POST", "/tenants", data, headers)
 response = httpServ.getresponse()
 print response.status, response.reason
 httpServ.close()
```