# Authenticated request to a RESTful API gives 404

Tags: python, rest

I want to use the BeyondWords RESTful API, with documentation [here](https://api.beyondwords.io/docs):

```
POST /projects/{project_id}/content (Create)
```

Unfortunately, they don't provide sample code, so I use their request body and these threads ([Calling REST API with an API key using the requests package in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53075939/calling-rest-api-with-an-api-key-using-the-requests-package-in-python) and [Python Post call throwing 400 Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659134/python-post-call-throwing-400-bad-request)) to write this code:

```
import requests

BEYOND_WORDS_KEY = "some_key"
BEYOND_WORDS_PROJECT = 12345

j = {
  "type": "auto_segment",
  "title": "<h1 data-beyondwords-marker=\"h1-title\">Example title</h1>",
  "summary": "<h2 data-beyondwords-marker=\"h2-summary\">This article is about TTS</h2>",
  "body": "<p data-beyondwords-marker=\"paragraph-1\">Example body</p>",
  "source_id": "example-source-id",
  "source_url": "https://example.com/some-article",
  "author": "John Smith",
  "image_url": "https://example.com/image.jpeg",
  "metadata": {
    "key": "value"
  },
  "published": True,
  "publish_date": "2023-01-01 00:00:00 UTC",
  "ads_enabled": True,
  "auto_segment_updates_enabled": True,
  "title_voice_id": 1,
  "summary_voice_id": 1,
  "body_voice_id": 1
}

headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth('apikey', BEYOND_WORDS_KEY)
response = requests.post(
    url="https://api.beyondwords.io/projects/%d/content" % BEYOND_WORDS_PROJECT,
    headers=headers,
    auth=auth,
    json=j
)

print(response, response.status_code, response.reason)
```

and the result is:

```
<Response [404]> 404 Not Found
```

Is my code correct, in which case I should contact the website for support?

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant ,but i didnt understand why have you passed  % BEYOND_WORDS_PROJECT in url params ? 404 status code simply states that page not found.

Comment: I edited the question to include the reason: the URL has to include the `project_id`. Thanks for the tip on 404: I tried the docs again, with the button `Try it out`, and the URL for the example with `curl` has a `v1` in the path, so it's `/v1/projects/{project_id}/content`. Now I get a 401, so my authentication isn't working. Do you want to write an answer for this one and I'll ask another question?

Comment: check this website they have sample code on how to use [link](https://developers.beyondwords.io/reference/contentcreate) , but you need to create a account with them, after creating a account, you will get project_id and api key, (create a project, after creating project click on setting and scroll down)you can use it.But unfortunately after sending correct api key and project_id its going into internal server error 500 status code, than after re-trying you get 422 status code ,there is some issue from their side.

Comment: Good job finding that page! The API key is set in the `X-Api-Header`, and then I get a 500 as well. Can you please post an answer?

Comment: Update: that command produced an effect, as the dashboard is showing a new item. But it has no text content and cannot be edited.